# Форма брони билетов на django

Tags: django

Подскажите пожалуста, принцип реализации бронирования мест, если это делать на django

Чтобы человек с своего акаунта на сайте забронировал и это отображалась и у него и в списке мест

Comment: 1. html и css тут явно не к месту. 2. на взгляд неспециалиста вопрос а) широковат и б) собственно и содержит ответ — именно принцип вы уже и изложили в последней фразе.

Comment: Да, вы правы, но моя проблема в том, что я не могу понять как лучше с технической части это скомпоновать